# Obtaining column based mean over unique multi index values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Good day awesome people,
I'm working on the dataframe on [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcYCN.png) and was looking to achieve [New table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGpht.png). I tried first obtaining the test score and total averages of the new table using :

```
df = pd.read_csv("testdata.csv")

grouped = df.groupby(["county_id","school_id","student_id"]).mean()

print (grouped)
```

It gives me this error:

> KeyError: 'county_id'

My plan is for the new table to be grouped based on `county_id, school_id and student_id`. However, for each of their unique indexes, the average of their test scores and the remarks based on a bandwidth of (`Excellent  20.0-25.0, Good 17.0-19.9 and Pass  16.9 - 14.0`) would be populated.

I will really appreciate anyone that could help out. Also, if it's possible to use a lambda function to achieve this will be cool too. Thank you

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the sample you provided (considering the table images you provided). However a ```KeyError:``` like that generally means that you've referenced a column/header that isn't in the data set. Are you spelling the column name correctly? And are you sure that name is a header in the data set?

Comment: Obviously your data doesn't have a `county_id` column, case is important. What does `df.head()` show?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @ralston I have cross checked the columns and it's same name as in my description.It does have a county_id and this is what df.head() gave me: 
school_id   county_id  student_id  test1  test2  test3  total_score  \
0           21          1        2154      2     12    0.5         14.5   
1           21          1        2154      3     11    1.5         15.5   
2           21          1        2154      4     10    2.5         16.5   
3           21          1        2233      5      9    3.5         17.5   
Couldn't populate the entire table per stackoverflow's limit

Comment: For any further help I/we will need you to edit your original post with the output of ```df.head()``` as code. If you don't know how to do this then type ```[pandas]``` in the StackOverflow search box (upper right). Without actually seeing what you have (in a formatted way), or without data to replicate the problem, I/we can't do much.